# How to update the Pgadmin4 docker image?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

How to update the `Pgadmin4` docker image without losing any the user's information in the folder`/var/lib/pgadmin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Pull the latest docker image

   `sudo docker pull dpage/pgadmin4`
2. Stop the running container

   `sudo docker stop pgadmin`
3. Remove existing container

   `sudo docker rm pgadmin`
4. Deploy/Run the latest images

   `sudo docker run --name pgadmin -p 80:80 -v /var/lib/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin  -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=m.thirumal@hotmail.com' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=thirumal' -d dpage/pgadmin4`

   or the below command for reverse proxy with `ngnix`

   `sudo docker run --name pgadmin -p 5050:80 -v /var/lib/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin  -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=m.thirumal@hotmail.com' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=thirumal' -d dpage/pgadmin4`

To `start` the docker container

```
`sudo docker start pgadmin`
```

For more information, refer: https://m-thirumal.github.io/installation_guide/#/pgadmin4/update_pgadmin4_docker_image

Answer (score 1):

The choosen answer is correct, but if you doesn't have any volume for your starting image yet you also have to do:

```
sudo docker cp name_of_your_image:/var/lib/pgadmin /var/lib/pgadmin
```

and

```
sudo chown -R 5050:5050 /var/lib/pgadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a docker named volume to permanently store the `/var/lib/pgadmin` folder.
Updating pgadmin's version then just requires changing the image name in my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.3
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ../pgadmin.env
    volumes:
      - my-pgadmin-volume:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - 5050:80
```